# Does an electric field create a pH gradient?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Since pH is a measure of the effective concentration of $\mathrm{H}^+$ ions a solution, I expect that an electric field applied to a solution will create a pH gradient. The higher concentration of $\mathrm{H}^+$ ions (corresponding to lower pH) should be close to the anion, and a lower concentration of $\mathrm{H}^+$ ions (corresponding to higher pH) should be closer to the cation.

This is a simple yes or no question. Does an electric field create a pH gradient as I described above? (If not, can you please provide an explanation?)

Comment: I would say that it makes sense that yes, it will create a pH gradient. I don't know about the order of magnitude of such a gradient and how it depends on the voltage. Let's hope someone does the experiment :)

Comment: Let's also hope someone provides a more thorough physical analysis... :)

Comment: Basically, we can take electrolysis as an example. You surely can promote a gradient of H+ concentration. I just don't know how much is it in terms of pH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, applying an electric field does create a pH gradient and in fact you can observe this simply by adding a suitable indicator to your system. For example see the section *Demonstration of pH Gradient Formation* in [this article](http://faculty.washington.edu/yagerp/microfluidicstutorial/transverseief/transverseief.htm).